# Java export jar including libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have been looking around for some time now, but didn't a find way how to export a `JAR` (not `runnable jar`) that contains in it's build path the referenced libraries.

Using `Eclipse`, I have included the `lib` folder which contains the jars of the referenced libraries in the export process.
Importing that JAR to another project and calling some method results in a `ClassNotFoundException`.
Looking at the MANIFEST, I didn't see any reference to those jars in the classpath, though the jars are indeed included in the jar.

So my questions are:
1. Is there any way to accomplish the packaging of the non-executable JAR so it will include libraries?
2. Is there any best practice for building and deploying a jar that include other jars libraries?

Comment: Another best practice is using `maven`

Comment: tick the option `Export java source files and resources` and `add directory entries`

Comment: Yes indeed maven is the best option, but it is not available in our organization ATM.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it too but it doesn't work for me. I added the final `.jar` file but it doesn't work.

So, I did a workaround.

1. Extract the `.jar` file that you want as a dependency.
2. Copy that content and put it all inside your `.jar` file.
3. Add your `.jar` file as dependency inside an eclipse project.
4. Run it and see if everything is ok.